# Is over here/ over there preposition?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adverbs, prepositional-phrases, syntax

I wonder if my knowledge is right regarding the following phrases being prepositions:

---

> **i) over here**
>
> **ii) over there**

Both having the same construction= **over** (preposition) + **here/there** (adverb)

Perhaps, I'm wrong about this.

Answer (score 1):

That preposition has many uses, one given by Lexico is [this](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/over):

> **over**
>   PREPOSITION
>
> **4.2** At the other side of; beyond.
>   *over the hill is a small village*

You can call out

> I am over here!

to someone who is looking for you, and

> The bus stop is over there.

to indicate where you wait for a bus.

Comment: Thus, over there/here = prepositional phrase?

Comment: Yes I think so.